# Why am I not able to pass a png with an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I've ran into a bit of a problem. I have a valid bytearray of a jpg, and a png which i'll prove below but for some reason when I pass the png intent I recieve a weird logcat (which i'll also provide below) and my screen is returned to the previous activity.

Ok this below fragment is called when the container of two fragments receives a messages that an item in another fragments list has been pressed (image below for ref). When an item in the list is pressed, this fragment below is removed from the container, and replaced with the new one and recieves the jsonInBytes & imageInBytes.

```
public class ImageAndSchematicPreviewFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_and_schematic_preview, container, false);

    Bundle extras = getArguments();

    // if there's passed arguments
    if (extras != null)
    {
       final byte[] jsonInBytes = extras.getByteArray("jsonInBytes");
       final byte[] imageInBytes = extras.getByteArray("imageInBytes");

        ByteArrayInputStream imageInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInBytes);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(imageInputStream);
        Bitmap imageForPreview = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageForPreview);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(jsonInBytes != null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ImageAndSchematicSchematicOnlyView.class);
                    intent.putExtra("imageInBytes", imageInBytes);
                    intent.putExtra("jsonInBytes", jsonInBytes);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ImageAndSchematicImageOnlyView.class);
                    intent.putExtra("imageInBytes", imageInBytes);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
    }
}
```

Here's the blank preview, when the fragment is loaded with no bundle:

[image]

When I tap on the JPG:

[image]

When I tap on the PNG:

[image]

As you can see, the image is being set in both cases with:

```
 ByteArrayInputStream imageInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInBytes);
 BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new    BufferedInputStream(imageInputStream);
 Bitmap imageForPreview = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(imageForPreview);
```

This for me atleast proves that the byte arrays are valid.

Right, so in the onClick I have 'ImageAndSchematicSchematicOnlyView' & 'ImageAndSchematicImageOnlyView' which are quite close with their names, and someone might think that it is the reciever of this information which is the problem, I can tell you that it is not and for the intent of proving the point i'll set them both to ImageAndSchematicImageOnlyView which takes them to a zoomable, larger etc image view. And it works, the .jpg is working. However, when I press the on the .png to enlarge it, I get this in the log cat, and i'm returned to the previous activity.

```
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame 20140421 Rev.6376
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ This is decoding
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ decoding stream->hasLength()
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecParseHeader call : QM
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ Qmage parsing for decoding ok
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode :  QmageHeader.NinePatched 0
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageHeader Height() 12 Width() : 522 sampleSize : 1
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ Qmage Make Color table
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ SkBitmap::kIndex8_Config == config && 1 == sampleSize
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : return true QM
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame 20140421 Rev.6376
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ This is decoding
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ decoding stream->hasLength()
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecParseHeader call : QM
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ Qmage parsing for decoding ok
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode :  QmageHeader.NinePatched 0
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageHeader Height() 135 Width() : 522 sampleSize : 1
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ normal image decoding
03-23 10:40:17.267    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame call : QM
03-23 10:40:17.277    8398-8417/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame 20140421 Rev.6376
03-23 10:40:17.277    8398-8417/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ This is decoding
03-23 10:40:17.277    8398-8417/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ decoding stream->hasLength()
03-23 10:40:17.277    8398-8417/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecParseHeader call : QM
03-23 10:40:17.277    8398-8417/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ Qmage parsing for decoding ok
03-23 10:40:17.277    8398-8417/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode :  QmageHeader.NinePatched 0
03-23 10:40:17.277    8398-8417/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageHeader Height() 135 Width() : 522 sampleSize : 1
03-23 10:40:17.277    8398-8417/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ normal image decoding
03-23 10:40:17.277    8398-8417/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame call : QM
03-23 10:40:17.287    8398-8420/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame 20140421 Rev.6376
03-23 10:40:17.287    8398-8420/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ This is decoding
03-23 10:40:17.297    8398-8420/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ decoding stream->hasLength()
03-23 10:40:17.297    8398-8420/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecParseHeader call : QM
03-23 10:40:17.297    8398-8420/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ Qmage parsing for decoding ok
03-23 10:40:17.297    8398-8420/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode :  QmageHeader.NinePatched 0
03-23 10:40:17.297    8398-8420/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageHeader Height() 12 Width() : 522 sampleSize : 1
03-23 10:40:17.297    8398-8420/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ Qmage Make Color table
03-23 10:40:17.297    8398-8420/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ SkBitmap::kIndex8_Config == config && 1 == sampleSize
03-23 10:40:17.297    8398-8420/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : return true QM
03-23 10:40:17.307    8398-8417/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : return true QM
03-23 10:40:17.337    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
03-23 10:40:17.337    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11634: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
03-23 10:40:17.337    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-23 10:40:17.337    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
03-23 10:40:17.337    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11640: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
03-23 10:40:17.337    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-23 10:40:17.337    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
03-23 10:40:17.337    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9308: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
03-23 10:40:17.337    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
03-23 10:40:17.347    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-23 10:40:17.347    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 495: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-23 10:40:17.347    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-23 10:40:17.347    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-23 10:40:17.347    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 517: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-23 10:40:17.347    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-23 10:40:17.377    8380-8416/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : return true QM
03-23 10:40:17.407    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx I/System.out﹕ show called
03-23 10:40:17.407    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame 20140421 Rev.6376
03-23 10:40:17.407    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ This is decoding
03-23 10:40:17.407    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ decoding stream->hasLength()
03-23 10:40:17.407    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecParseHeader call : QM
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ Qmage parsing for decoding ok
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode :  QmageHeader.NinePatched 0
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageHeader Height() 48 Width() : 48 sampleSize : 1
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ Qmage Make Color table
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ SkBitmap::kIndex8_Config == config && 1 == sampleSize
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : return true QM
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame 20140421 Rev.6376
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ This is decoding
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ decoding stream->hasLength()
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecParseHeader call : QM
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ Qmage parsing for decoding ok
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode :  QmageHeader.NinePatched 0
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageHeader Height() 48 Width() : 48 sampleSize : 1
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ normal image decoding
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame call : QM
03-23 10:40:17.417    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx E/Qmage﹕ onDecode : return true QM
03-23 10:40:17.507    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx D/GC﹕ <tid=8398> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver rls_pxa988_KK44_GC13.20
03-23 10:40:17.527    8398-8398/com.xxxx.xxxx D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

FYI. This doesn't occur on the successful transition to the .jpeg enlarged view.

It's not a huge deal as we make the software that outputs to this software so could in theory have a png converter but i don't feel like it should be necessary. Any help would be appreciated, any questions are welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Hi can you tell me what are you using for enlarge the JPEG file.  It seems like you received the raw data correct. but when you try to place inside the enlarge image view they might have issue. just tell what are you used for image enlarge.

Comment: Hi Bhavdip, thanks for the response. I'm just using the exact same method as what I used in the above method, it's just simply the fact that it's on a bigger screen with no list, and has the ability to scroll & zoom about. I've tried pushing these two images to simply blank activities, and still, it happens.

Comment: Hi Can you show the code of ImageAndSchematicSchematicOnlyView.class and ImageAndSchematicImageOnlyView.class what are you doing in this class.

Comment: Did you tried with different png file ?

Comment: I'll try that now Bhavdip, I don't feel there's much point to post the classes as it's happening to a blank activity too. Thanks

Comment: `I can tell you that it is not and for the intent of proving the point i'll set them both to ... ` No. If you want to prove that it is not the receiver than do not start the receiver. Only iniiate the intents. Comment or remove startActivityForResult.

Comment: We need to debug the code when you select the PNG file option. Check that it should pass the byte data to the intent activity in a correct way. if you could see the byte data in debug mode during the PNG file selected then you need to look up the image view where you want to set the PNG file.

Comment: It was a bad png, thanks Bhavdip.

Comment: ohh ! finally it was issue of PNG file.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much. I didn't know this could occur while the image was valid, very strange

Comment: Yes you are right because if the code execute the JPEG file in correctly then the same code defiantly should work with PNG file.